# Should typos be edited if multiple comments mention it?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question with two code fragments included.  I accidentally switched the order of the two, saying that the working fragment didn't work and vice versa.  Multiple comments answering my intended question pointed out my error.

In such a case, should I edit the question to correct the typo? If I do, this can cause confusion to future readers of the question, seeing comments that reference a typo that doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: You should of course always fix problems in your post, be it question or answer. Comments can be flagged as obsolete afterwards if they no longer apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SO posts are intented to stay on line for a long time. As such, they sould be made better and clearer every time possible.

So if you had a typo in the question, you should fix it. If others pointed out the error, you can just leave a comment saying you fixed the post due to those comments. That way :

- you are not rude for those who helped you : their comments may no longer be relevant, but you gave them credit for the fix
- future readers are not annoyed by the typo
- the post will be nicer

If you want to clean that all later, you can even flag the comments as no longer relevant and delete your own - but IMHO it is better to wait some time to let commenters see that you used their comment and gave them credit for that.